# Bootstrap wells and panels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning about panels and wells in Bootstrap.
They seem very similar to me.

I would just like to know what is the difference if any between a panel and a well in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look closely, all panel does is apply some basic border and padding to contain some content.

Whereas a well is a container that causes the content to appear sunken or an inset effect on the page.

Additionally you can have a panel header, body and footer. That is not possible in wells. This is because wells are used for decorative purposes or for standing out. But panels provide a much complex structure where you can have a header, body and footer to make some content stand out.

Comment: Hi Vivek I now understand the differences between these two components, thanks.